# Use select on pipe returns 10038

Tags: c, winapi, error-handling, pipe

I have problem with pipes. I'm creating pipes with `::_pipe` function and want to use `select` on it but `WSAGetLastError` returns `10038` and kua is -1. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winbase.h>
#include <FileAPI.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
  WORD wVersionRequested;
  wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
  WSADATA wsaData;

  WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
  int fd[2];
  _pipe(&fd[2], 65536, 0);
  FD_SET set;

  FD_SET((unsigned int) (fd[0]), (&set));

  timeval time;
  time.tv_sec = 1;
  time.tv_usec = 0;
  int kua = select(0, &set, NULL, NULL, &time);
  printf("last ->%d\n",  WSAGetLastError());
  fflush(stdout);
  }
```

Please dont pay attention on headers, I've read some topics which had same error but none of them where like this(pipe created this way). Hope you can help. Thanks.

**EDIT**
I changed code a little bit now its `_pipe(fd, 65536, 0);` but in this case it gives me seg fault.

Comment: From the documentation: *The select function returns the total number of socket handles that are ready and contained in the fd_set structures, zero if the time limit expired, or SOCKET_ERROR if an error occurred. If the return value is SOCKET_ERROR, WSAGetLastError can be used to retrieve a specific error code.* You did not check the return value. Why not?

Comment: sorry, I checked now, its -1 I'll edit

Comment: Also `fd[2]` is off the end of the array so you are corrupting the stack. And can you even pass a pipe to select?

Comment: You aren't checking for errors when calling `_pipe` either. Not really a very good show. No error checking, stack corruption,  and an error code that could hardly be clearer. The system tells you that you are passing something that is not a socket. Obvious conclusion: a pipe is not a socket. What did you think 10038 meant?

Comment: Have you considered looking up Winsock error 10038?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most platforms, pipes and sockets are both represented using file descriptors, and as such both can be used with file I/O functions that operate on file descriptors, including `select()`.

However, on Windows, sockets and pipes are distinct object types, and are not represented using file descriptors at all.  `select()` only supports sockets, not files or pipes.  That is why you are getting error 10038, aka [`WSAENOTSOCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx):

> Socket operation on nonsocket.
>   **An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket**. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.

There is no equivalent of `select()` for pipe objects created by `_pipe()`.  All you can do is read and write.

If you need to detect when data arrives on a pipe before reading it, use `CreatePipe()` and `PeekNamedPipe()` instead of `_pipe()`.  Otherwise, consider using Overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port instead.  That will allow you to start an asynchronous read operation in the background and let it notify you when it has received data.

Comment: One question please: Can I make non-blocking read on pipe created by _pipe?

Comment: @Rasty on Linux, yes, using the `O_NONBLOCK` or `O_ASYNC` flag of `pipe()`. But on Windows, AFAIK `_pipe()` does not support those flags. Use a Win32 pipe instead, like I suggested earlier.